# Issue with collecting data inputted in a text box

Tags: javascript, html

[Link is to the whole of the code.I did not originally write this I simply edited it](https://pastebin.com/QU74wrtj).

So I am editing a survey to fit my needs for some research I'm trying to conduct for my psychology masters thesis. I have put an age and a code (for participant withdrawal) input which shows up on the survey, but I need to know how to get the script to record the input of both age and personal code. (I understand how it collects inputs for radio inputs but not text inputs)
So below is the code where it calls on the form for inputting the age of the participant which works. But it doesn't record the answer.

Here is where the forms are called.
These are the forms.
And here is the array containing all the answers. Which I need to some how add age input and code input too.
I have also added where the answers are posted too.

```js
if (currSlide == 1) {
  var d = new Date();
  startTime = d.getTime();

  document.getElementById("Next").style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById("slide0").style.display = "none";

  var ex = document.getElementById("code_input");
  ex.style.left = string_l + "px";
  ex.style.top = string_t;
  ex.style.display = "block";
  currSlide++;



} else if (currSlide == 2) {
  var code_val = $(document.getElementById("code_input"))


  if (document.getElementById("CodeID").value.length == 0) {

    promptNonresponse();
    document.getElementById("CodeID").value = "  "
  } else {


    document.getElementById("slide0").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("code_input").style.display = "none";

    var ex = document.getElementById("age_input");
    ex.style.left = string_l + "px";
    ex.style.top = string_t;
    ex.style.display = "block";
    currSlide++;
  }


} else if (currSlide == 3) {
  var age_val = $(document.getElementById("age_input"))

  if (document.getElementById("AgeID").value.length == 0) {

    promptNonresponse();
    document.getElementById("AgeID").value = "  "
  } else {



    document.getElementById("slide0").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("age_input").style.display = "none";
   
    checked = true;

  // Single array containing all answers
  var answer = [document.getElementById("nomem").value, nodes[0].q1, (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].name : "", (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].name : "", (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].name : "", (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].name : "", (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].name : "", (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].name : "", (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].name : "", (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].name : "", (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].name : "", (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].name : "", (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].name : "", (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].name : "", (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].name : "", (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].name : "", (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].friendsWith : "", (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].name : "", (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].q2 : "", (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].friendsWith : "", nodes[0].q5, nodes[0].q6, nodes[0].q7, nodes[0].q8, nodes[0].q9, nodes[0].q10, nodes[0].q11, nodes[0].q12, nodes[0].q13, nodes[0].q14, nodes[0].q15, nodes[0].q16, nodes[0].q17, nodes[0].q18, nodes[0].q19, nodes[0].q20, nodes[0].q21, nodes[0].q22, nodes[0].q23, nodes[0].q24, nodes[0].q25, nodes[0].q26, nodes[0].q27, nodes[0].q28, nodes[0].q29, nodes[0].q30, nodes[0].q31, nodes[0].q32, nodes[0].q33, nodes[0].q34, nodes[0].q35, nodes[0].q36, nodes[0].q37, nodes[0].q38, nodes[0].q39, nodes[0].q40];

  console.log(answer)

  window.addEventListener("load", e => {
    document.getElementById("qu1_id").value = answer.join(",");
  })

    //Post collected data to handler for recording
        $.post( "save_results.php", {
        nomem: document.getElementById("nomem").value,
        q1: nodes[0].q1,
        q2_1: (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].name : "",
        q3_1: (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].q2 : "",
        q4_1: (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].friendsWith : "",
        q2_2: (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].name : "",
        q3_2: (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].q2 : "",
        q4_2: (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].friendsWith : "",
        q2_3: (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].name : "",
        q3_3: (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].q2 : "",
        q4_3: (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].friendsWith : "",
        q2_4: (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].name : "",
        q3_4: (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].q2 : "",
        q4_4: (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].friendsWith : "",
        q2_5: (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].name : "",
        q3_5: (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].q2 : "",
        q4_5: (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].friendsWith : "",
        q2_6: (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].name : "",
        q3_6: (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].q2 : "",
        q4_6: (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].friendsWith : "",
        q2_7: (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].name : "",
        q3_7: (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].q2 : "",
        q4_7: (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].friendsWith : "",
        q2_8: (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].name : "",
        q3_8: (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].q2 : "",
        q4_8: (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].friendsWith : "",
        q2_9: (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].name : "",
        q3_9: (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].q2 : "",
        q4_9: (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].friendsWith : "",
        q2_10: (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].name : "",
        q3_10: (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].q2 : "",
        q4_10: (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].friendsWith : "",
        q2_11: (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].name : "",
        q3_11: (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].q2 : "",
        q4_11: (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].friendsWith : "",
        q2_12: (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].name : "",
        q3_12: (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].q2 : "",
        q4_12: (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].friendsWith : "",
        q2_13: (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].name : "",
        q3_13: (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].q2 : "",
        q4_13: (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].friendsWith : "",
        q2_14: (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].name : "",
        q3_14: (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].q2 : "",
        q4_14: (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].friendsWith : "",
        q2_15: (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].name : "",
        q3_15: (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].q2 : "",
        q4_15: (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].friendsWith : "",
        q5: nodes[0].q5,
        q6: nodes[0].q6,
        q7: nodes[0].q7,
        q8: nodes[0].q8,
        q9: nodes[0].q9,
        q10: nodes[0].q10,
        q11: nodes[0].q11,
        q12: nodes[0].q12,
        q13: nodes[0].q13,
        q14: nodes[0].q14,
        q15: nodes[0].q15,
        q16: nodes[0].q16,
        q17: nodes[0].q17,
        q18: nodes[0].q18,
        q19: nodes[0].q19,
        q20: nodes[0].q20,
        q21: nodes[0].q21,
        q22: nodes[0].q22,
        q23: nodes[0].q23,
        q24: nodes[0].q24,
        q25: nodes[0].q25,
        q26: nodes[0].q26,
        q27: nodes[0].q27,
        q28: nodes[0].q28,
        q29: nodes[0].q29,
        q30: nodes[0].q30,
        q31: nodes[0].q31,
        q32: nodes[0].q32,
        q33: nodes[0].q33,
        q34: nodes[0].q34,
        q35: nodes[0].q35,
        q36: nodes[0].q36,
        q37: nodes[0].q37,
        q38: nodes[0].q38,
        q39: nodes[0].q39,
        q40: nodes[0].q40
        });

        checked = false


        var sf = document.getElementById("submitForm");
        var sb = document.getElementById("submitButton");
        var nd = document.getElementById("NextDiv");
        sf.style.display = "block";
        nd.style.display = "none";
        var motivationText = d3.select("svg").append("text")
          .attr("class", "slideText")
          .attr("id", "motivationText")
          .attr("x", center - (textWidth / 2) + 50)
          .attr("y", text_offset_top + 40)
          .text("Thank you for participating in this study. Click \"Next\" to end the survey.")
          .call(wrap, textWidth);

        // Release window close-prevention
        unhook();

      }
```

```html
<div class="input-group" display="none" id="code_input" method="get">
  <span class="slideText">Please enter a word that you will remember in case you wish to withdraw your data from this study.</span><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="CodeID" name="code" class="form-control" placeholder="..." size="10">
</div>


<div class="input-group" display="none" id="age_input" method="get">
  <span class="slideText">Please state your age</span><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="AgeID" name="age" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" size="10">
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been stuck on this for hours. If you need any more of my code please let me know. I tried looking at other questions around this topic but I could not figure out how to amend it to my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand what you're asking? What are you trying to do with the data when it is submitted or how are you trying to store it?

Comment: As you can now see, there is a syntax error in this code. Can you please edit this snippet to create a working example?

Comment: Hopefully the edit I've done answers your question. I've put in the post section too. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the value of a text field is quite easy. In your javascript you would just do:

```
var userCode = document.getElementById("CodeID").value;
var userAge = document.getElementById("AgeID").value;
```

Then you can just add userCode, and userAge to your answer array;

```
answers = [your current array, userCode, userAge];
```

Comment: Right it did something, but now I'm getting this error when I call for answers through console.log(answer) . I get this where the age and code should appear: ["<br />↵<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error x…>↵<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="

Comment: @Connmal Are you assigning the value of the useCode input, and the userId input using php at all? The code your getting when you log the answer array looks like the start of some php error output.

Comment: Yes the whole document I posted above is in one php file. And I call on the code_input before I used your suggestion.

Comment: @Connmal Is it possible to see the php file?

Comment: I have posted it to a paste bin, I've put the link in my post. Its a large bit of script that I did not originally write, more I simply edited it.